# SQL Server Roll-up (Sum) Value from associative table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation. I have a “Client” Table (Parent) and an “Opportunity” Table Child table.  (See example below).

Client Table

```
| Id   | Name     
------------------
|1     | Client A 
|2     | Client B 
|3     | Client C
```

Opportunity Table

```
| Id   | ClientId       |   Value
---------------------------------
| 10   | 1              |   1000 
| 11   | 1              |   3000 
| 12   | 2              |   1500 
| 13   | 3              |   2000
```

I want to show sum of all Total of Opportunity Value  (OppValue) on the client record.

Expected Output

```
| Id   | Name     |   OppValue 
-----------------------------
|1     | Client A |     4000 
|2     | Client B |     1500 
|3     | Client C |     2000
```

The business requirement is to filter on “OppValue” with the following criteria greater than, less than or null, etc but not by opportunity create date, etc. We are expecting each year users will be adding 500 clients and 45000 new opportunities. Based on the above I can think of three options

1. Calculate OppValue using SQL Query (Group By or Partition By)
2. Create View or Calculated Field using UDF
3. Create a new field in the “Client” table and populate it using Application business logic (outside SQL).

Which of the solution in your opinion will work best in terms of User experience (speed) and maintenance?
In case there is a better suggestion please let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a view:

```
create view client_opp as (
     select c.*, o.oppvalue
     from client c outer apply
          (select sum(oppvalue) as oppvalue
           from opportunities o
           where o.clientId = c.clientId
          ) o;
```

Be sure you have an index on `opportunities(clientId, oppvalue)` -- or at least on `opportunities(clientId)`.  Note that this uses `apply` quite specifically so the view should work well even when used in a query with additional filtering.

If this works performance-wise, then you are done.  Other methods using triggers and UDFs require a bit more maintenance in the database.  You can definitely use them, but I would recommend waiting to see if this meets your performance needs.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach, the performance is good I have run few performance test.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query using `inner join` and `sum()` function. To know more about inner join you can follow this [link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-inner-join/). You can learn in detail about the [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL) here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Create table Client
(Id int, Name Varchar(20))

insert into Client values
(1, 'Client A'),
(2, 'Client B'),
(3, 'Client C')


create table Opportunity
(Id int, ClientId int, Value int)

insert into Opportunity values
(10, 1, 1000 ),
(11, 1, 3000 ),
(12, 2, 1500 ),
(13, 3, 2000 )

Select Client.Id, Client.Name, sum(Value) as Value
from Client
inner join Opportunity on Client.Id = Opportunity.ClientId       
group by Client.Id, Client.Name
```

Output

```
Id  Name       Value
----------------------
1   Client A    4000
2   Client B    1500
3   Client C    2000
```

To create a view you can use the following create view example.

Syntax:

```
Create View <ViewName> 
as
<View Query>
```

Example:

```
create view MyView
as
Select Client.Id, Client.Name, sum(Value) as Value
from Client
inner join Opportunity on Client.Id = Opportunity.ClientId       
group by Client.Id, Client.Name
```

Selecting the result from a view as created above.

```
select * from MyView
```

Comment: I was more looking for a recommendation based on the 3 possible approaches that I have suggested in my post. This answer gives two options either use a query or create a view? it is not very  clear which one should be used and the advantages of using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
create view client_view as
     select c.*, ot.OppValue
     from ClientTable c cross apply
          ( select sum(value) as OppValue 
            from OpportunityTable ot 
            where ot.ClientId = c.ClientId
          ) ot;
```